# CSS: A similar effect to placing an element's box shadow at a different z-index than the element

Tags: html, css, z-index, box-shadow

I have a container which holds an image and a panel the appears when you hover over that image. I am trying to get the box shadow on the panel to appear behind the image, while the rest of the panel overlaps the image.

[What I have vs. What I'd like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmr9A.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="icon" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
  <div class="sum-container left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container .sum-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: solid 5px blue;
    background-color: white;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 5;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: .250s;
}

.container .sum-container.left {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: -5px;
    border-right: none;
    padding-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #888888;
}

.container .icon:hover + .sum-container {
    z-index: 6;
    opacity: 1;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 20px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.icon {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 480px;
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #888888;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    user-drag: none;
}
```

I've included a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kristian221/0j34u4bf/) as well.

Also, still new here. If anyone can suggest a better title, please let me know. I realize you can't actually set multiple z-indexes for one element, but I'm looking for a solution with a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the end goal, you can make the shadow a pseudo element with a negative `z-index` and remove the `z-index` from `.sum-container` and `.sum-container` will be over `.icon` and it's pseudo element will be under both of them.

```css
.container .sum-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: solid 5px blue;
    background-color: white;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: .250s;
}

.sum-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  background: #888;
  transform: translate(0,10px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.container .sum-container.left {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: -5px;
    border-right: none;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.container .icon:hover + .sum-container {
    opacity: 1;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 20px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.icon {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 480px;
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #888888;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    user-drag: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="icon" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
  <div class="sum-container left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the result I'm looking for, however by removing the z-index in '.sum-container' the panel will go under icons in other '.container' elements if they appear after it. Also I'd like to keep the '.sum-container''s overflow property if possible.

Comment: @Afropenguinn the problem with a `z-index` on `.sum-container` is if you define one, that will start a new stacking order, and if it is higher than `.icon`, it will be impossible to put the pseudo element under `.icon`. That only works if `.sum-container` doesn't have a `z-index`.

Comment: Actually, thanks to your implementation, I managed to get it sorted. I put a wrapper around content in the .sum-container and set it to overflow: hidden, which allowed me to place elements outside of .sum-container. From there I made a pseudo element that is positioned just below .sum-container with a height of 5 and the color of my box shadow. Because of this I was also able to keep the z-index on the .sum-container, since the "shadow" is not overlapping with the .sum-container.

Comment: @Afropenguinn nice! glad you figured it out.